# How to disable onPress flatlist item with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a flatlist. And I want to disable the onPress function when  data.subcategories.length == 0. So that a user can't can't click futher. Because if a user click on the last itme there are not items anymore in the flatlist.

So this is the component:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const [subCatgoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSubCategoryData(route.params.subcategories).then((data) => {
            if (data.animals.length > 0) {
                setSubCategoryList(data.animals);
                setLoading(false);
            } else {
                setSubCategoryList(data.subcategories);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        });
    }, [route]);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {isLoading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <CategoryList
                data={subCatgoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

Question: how to disable onPress when `data.subcategories.length == 0`

Comment: ?? Who gave this post a d-vote?? For what??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `disabled` props to your `TouchableOpacity` component:

```js
<CategoryList
  data={subCatgoryList}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}
        disabled={loading || index === subCatgoryList.length - 1}
       >
         <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
         <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item} />
         </Spacer>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     );
  }}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
/>
```